Why does my task run slow when using Task.Result but fast when I use await Task?
When I run the below code as part of my application, replacing the line var capacityScenarios = debouncer.Result; with the following line: var capacityScenarios = await debouncer; results in a massive performance increase. About 3 minutes of execution time difference and the amount is greater as the amount of days / threads increases.
I noticed this because we only recently included some asynchronous functionality into some previously existing classes. As such instead of adjusting all classes up the tree to return Task<T> at certain points I simply just performed a .Wait or a .Result on a task.
I know that .Wait or .Result holds the thread and also creates a new one to run the task but I don't understand how that results in such dramatic execution swings. Am I doing something wrong anywhere in my logic that might account for this?
Edit: My debouncer class simply stalls a call that would ideally take an enumerable as input so that a bunch of threads can individually make calls to it and after some timeout period the original call would be made with the appropriately aggregated enumerable (instead of one off calls). The debouncer makes each calling thread wait on a single task, so each thread will complete at the same time, once the debouncer completes. I included it here so anyone could demonstrate the slowness for themselves and see the underlying design in case that plays into any design improvement suggestions.
public void SlowOrFastFunction(){
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
    //Note async usage is only here for commenting in the faster await call. Remove async when using .Result call as it's not needed.
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var debouncer = Debouncer.Debounce("Simulation", 3000, date, (input) =>
        {
            return input;
        }, (inputs) =>
        {
            return inputs.Select(i =>
            {
                return i
            }).ToArray();
        });
        //var capacityScenarios = await debouncer;
        var capacityScenarios = debouncer.Result;
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

public static class Debouncer
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<Task, DateTime, List<object>>> _taskTimeInputDictionary = new();
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Tuple<object, DateTime>> _processLockDictionary = new();
    public async static Task<T> Debounce<inputT, aggrigateOutput, T>(string uniqueKey, int milliseconds, inputT input, Func<List<inputT>, aggrigateOutput> inputAggregator, Func<aggrigateOutput, T> action, bool singleThreaded = false, ILogger? logger = null)
    {
        Task<T> task = null;
        var processLockDictionary = _processLockDictionary.GetOrAdd(uniqueKey + $"_ProcessLock {(singleThreaded ? "_ST" : "")}", new Tuple<object, DateTime>(new object(), DateTime.Now));
        var processLock = processLockDictionary.Item1;
        _processLockDictionary.TryUpdate(uniqueKey + $"_ProcessLock {(singleThreaded ? "_ST" : "")}", new Tuple<object, DateTime>(processLock, DateTime.Now), processLockDictionary);
        lock (processLock)
        {
            var dictionaryRecord = _taskTimeInputDictionary.AddOrUpdate(uniqueKey + "_Task",
                (key) => //key not found - create new
                {
                    logger?.LogInformation("Adding dictionary record for " + uniqueKey);
                    return new Tuple<Task, DateTime, List<object>>(null, DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds), new List<object>() { input });
                },
                (key, tt) =>
                {
                    tt.Item3.Add(input);
                    return new Tuple<Task, DateTime, List<object>>(tt.Item1, DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds), tt.Item3);
                }
            );
            if (dictionaryRecord.Item1 == null)
            {
                Task<T> temptask = BuildTask(uniqueKey, inputAggregator, action, singleThreaded, logger, processLock);
                _taskTimeInputDictionary.TryUpdate(uniqueKey + "_Task", new Tuple<Task, DateTime, List<object>>(temptask, dictionaryRecord.Item2, dictionaryRecord.Item3), dictionaryRecord);
                task = temptask;
            }
            else
            {
                task = dictionaryRecord.Item1 as Task<T>;
            }
        }
        //await Task.Delay(10000);
        return await task;
        //await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
        //return default(T);
    }

    private static Task<T> BuildTask<inputT, aggrigateOutput, T>(string uniqueKey, Func<List<inputT>, aggrigateOutput> inputAggregatorFunc, Func<aggrigateOutput, T> processFunc, bool singleThreaded, ILogger? logger, object processLock)
    {
        try
        {
            return TimedExecutor(uniqueKey, inputAggregatorFunc, processFunc, singleThreaded, processLock, logger);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger?.LogError("Error triggering timed executor. Returning Null: " + ex);
            return Task.FromResult(default(T));
        }
    }

    private static Task<T> TimedExecutor<inputT, aggregatorOutput, T>(string uniqueKey, Func<List<inputT>, aggregatorOutput> inputAggregatorFunc, Func<aggregatorOutput, T> processFunc, bool singleThreaded, object processLock, ILogger? logger)
    {
        aggregatorOutput input = default(aggregatorOutput);
        bool Run;
        DateTime executeTime;

        var dictionaryRecord = _taskTimeInputDictionary[uniqueKey + "_Task"];
        executeTime = dictionaryRecord.Item2;
        Run = DateTime.Now > executeTime;

        if (Run)
        {
            lock (processLock)
            {
                _taskTimeInputDictionary.Remove(uniqueKey + "_Task", out dictionaryRecord);
                input = inputAggregatorFunc(dictionaryRecord.Item3.Select(i => (inputT)i).ToList());
                logger?.LogInformation("Executing debouncer action for " + uniqueKey + ". Removing dictionary record.");
                //Clean up process lock dictionary
                _processLockDictionary.Where(i =>
                {
                    var accessDiff = DateTime.Now.Ticks - i.Value.Item2.Ticks;
                    var remove = TimeSpan.FromTicks(accessDiff) > TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
                    return remove;
                }).ForEach(i =>
                {
                    _processLockDictionary.TryRemove(i.Key, out _);
                });
            }
            if (singleThreaded && Run)
            {
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var result = processFunc(input);
                        return Task.FromResult(result);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger?.LogError("Error executing debouncer action. Returning null from action: " + ex);
                        return Task.FromResult(default(T));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                };
            }
        }
        if (!singleThreaded && Run)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = processFunc(input);
                return Task.FromResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger?.LogError("Error executing debouncer action. Returning null from action: " + ex);
                return Task.FromResult(default(T));
            }
        }

        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(25);
            return await BuildTask(uniqueKey, inputAggregatorFunc, processFunc, singleThreaded, logger, processLock);
        });
    }
}


"... and also creates a new one to run the task" How did you know this?

I believe I learned it while watching a task deep dive course on youtube while trying to understand this issue.

Tasks are scheduled by schedulers and may or may not run on a new thread. Your compiler should also warn you that the async method lacks await and will run synchronously.

"As such instead of adjusting all classes up the tree to return Task at certain points I simply just performed a .Wait or a .Result on a task." - exactly what you should not  do ...

"I know that .Wait or .Result holds the thread and also creates a new one to run the task" - no it doesn't (create a new thread). The task is running or not completely independently - it doesn't even need to be a CPU oriented operation. If the pending task is on the thread-pool, then you can also be constrained by thread-pool capacity and growth, but that has nothing to do with your choice to use .Result/.Wait(). Either that YouTube video you watched was wrong, or at best: there is some missing context/nuance, because in the general case: nope, that's not how it works

Shingo, the async addition for task.run call was only added for the case of the demo. Your right that it warns about it here. Prior to adding await I didn't have async on the task declaration because it wasn't needed.

Fildor are you saying that what I was avoiding doing (covering all function results to task) is what I'm supposed to do? I'm this case I controlled the classes and functions so I was luck enough to be able to do it but what if I didn't?

Marc sure my understanding of tasks might not be perfect but I'm general task.wait should make the current thread wait until the underlying task is complete. Your saying thread pool capacity could affect the execution... I had thought maybe something like that might be coming into play but had no means to validate the claim. Maybe i can look into how to prove/disprove that case.

"About 3 minutes of execution time difference and the amount is greater as the amount of days / threads increases." -- It would be more insightful to share the percentile improvement in performance, not the absolute difference. 3 minutes might be a negligible improvement if the whole operation take 8 hours to complete. So what is the percentile improvement?

Also please try increasing preemptively the number of threads that the ThreadPool creates immediately on demand, using the SetMinThreads method: ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);, and tell us if it makes any difference.

Sorry getting back to this so late. It does seem like ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100,100) does seem to speed it up significantly. Down from 3 min down to about 45sec . However, it seems like simply using async await and adjusting all functions down the line to return a task of the original result runs in about 3 seconds. So async await is the clear winning solution, but increasing the number of threads it's able to create does seem reasonable. I just am not personally one for missing with the thread pool.

"Fildor are you saying that what I was avoiding doing...is what I'm supposed to do?" Yes. "what if I didn't [control the classes]?" You would have to accept the poor performance that comes from blocking threads; the next-best option simply isn't the best option. That's why Microsoft and others have been going out of their way to add Async versions of just about every method that might do something async.

"task.wait should make the current thread wait until the underlying task is complete": That is true. But it does not "also creates a new one to run the task." So if the Task you're waiting on needs a thread that isn't available for one reason or another (e.g. running low on threads, or contending for a UI thread), that thread may take a very long time to unblock. If you end up with a cyclic thread dependency, you might hit deadlock.
